# How to link polygons from different file to google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps api v3 for my project and i'm using a set of polygon coordinates to highlight a region. But i'm highlighting 15 regions and each regions have more than 100 polygon coordinates. Is there any way i can create another file where i can put  all the coordinates with their corresponding region's name and i can use those regions name in my html page.
Here is my code

```
var kerala = new google.maps.Polygon({
map: map,
paths: [
new google.maps.LatLng(12.758232,74.86084),
new google.maps.LatLng(12.736801,75.014648),
new google.maps.LatLng(12.329269,75.432129),
new google.maps.LatLng(12.093039,75.794678),
new google.maps.LatLng(11.942601,75.959473),
/* n number of coordinates */
],
strokeColor: '#873600',
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillColor: '#873600',
fillOpacity: 0.5
});
```

But i want something like this

```
var kerala = new google.maps.Polygon({
map: map,
paths: /* here i should give the name of a region, which will be defined with coordinates in another file */
});
```

Some one please help me with this , i don't even know how to define that polygon coordinate file, and which extension should that file be defined with.

Answer (score 0):

**make array of state name with latlng object and use as a path**

**example:**

```
var maharashtraArray = [];

maharashtraArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng("latitude","longitude"))
```

*then use this array as polygon path*

```
var kerala = new google.maps.Polygon({
map: map,
paths: maharashtraArray
});
```